# How to stop Mac from jumping to a program when a new window opens?

Tags: applications, desktop, window-manager, mission-control, matlab

This seems like a very specific weird question that I can't find an answer to anywhere else.

I am making hundreds of figures in MATLAB. I plot each figure and then save it as a png to look at later. I am doing this in a for loop so each figure pops up for one second, saves, and then closes. On a Windows machine, I used to start the for loop and then go work on other things in other programs while the MATLAB program ran. However, I am now working on a Mac and every time a new figure is opened in MATLAB, my computer jumps back to MATLAB as the active window. So it's impossible to do anything while the script is running because every 1-2 seconds, MATLAB pops back up and I have to navigate back to whatever other app I was using. I've tried minimizing MATLAB, and I've tried creating a new desktop in Mission Control. But it just keeps jumping back to MATLAB every time a new figure window opens.

I'm not sure if this is a Mac question or a MATLAB question, but I haven't found any answers on any MATLAB help so thought I would ask here too.

Any help is appreciated.

I am using MATLAB 2021a on a 2019 13-in MacBook Pro with Big Sur 11.3.

Comment: That is a matlab issue you should be able to create png files without outputting them to the screen